# Inconsistent Accessibility: Property Type Error

Tags: c#

I've done the googling to no avail. This is the one sole error preventing my code from compiling and running but I can't seem to figure it out. The exact text of the error is "...Dictionary is less accessible than property FleetAirliner.InsuranceProperties"

Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
namespace TheAirline.Model.AirlinerModel
{
[Serializable]
public class FleetAirliner
{
    public Airliner Airliner { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Airport Homebase { get; set; }
    public enum PurchasedType { Bought, Leased,BoughtDownPayment }
    public DateTime PurchasedDate { get; set; }
    public PurchasedType Purchased { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasRoute { get { return this.Routes.Count > 0; } set { ;} }
    public AirlinerStatistics Statistics { get; set; }

    /*Changed for deleting routeairliner*/
    public enum AirlinerStatus { Stopped, On_route, On_service, Resting, To_homebase, To_route_start }
    public AirlinerStatus Status { get; set; }
    public Coordinates CurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public List<Route> Routes { get; private set; }
    public Flight CurrentFlight { get; set; }
    public DateTime GroundedToDate { get; set; }
    public List<Pilot> Pilots { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AirlinerInsurance> InsurancePolicies { get; set; } //error occurs here
    public int NumberOfPilots {get {return this.Pilots.Count;} private set {;}}
    public FleetAirliner(PurchasedType purchased,DateTime purchasedDate, Airline airline,Airliner airliner,Airport homebase)
    {
        this.Airliner = airliner;
        this.Purchased = purchased;
        this.PurchasedDate = purchasedDate;
        this.Airliner.Airline = airline;
        this.Homebase = homebase;
        this.Name = airliner.TailNumber;
        this.Statistics = new AirlinerStatistics(this);

        this.Status = AirlinerStatus.Stopped;

        this.CurrentPosition = new Coordinates(this.Homebase.Profile.Coordinates.Latitude, this.Homebase.Profile.Coordinates.Longitude);

        this.Routes = new List<Route>();
        this.Pilots = new List<Pilot>();
        this.InsurancePolicies = new Dictionary<string, AirlinerInsurance>();
    }
```

Comment: whats the definition of AirlinerInsurance?

Comment: `class AirlinerInsurance {  ..constructors..  public AirlinerInsurance(InsuranceType insType, InsuranceScope insScope, PaymentTerms paymentTerms, int insAmount) {  ... } }`

All the non-int parameters are enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that class "AirlinerInsurance" Is not Public.

It is a property that is public, but other classes, that are allowed to use the property, might not have access rights to the class itself (it is private / internal).

**Edit**
Now that you have posted the code of class "AirlinerInsurance", just add a "public" modifier to it.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992928/c-inconsistent-accessibility-property-type) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I did that just prior to you posting this :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
class AirlinerInsurance {
  // stuff
}
```

to be

```
public class AirlinerInsurance {
  //stuff
}
```