# Adding migration for a new table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created model named "Allocation" but when I am running Add-Migration "Allocation for Deals" then the migration file which is opened with up() and down() functions has no any query within the functions and table is not created in database.

My Model is:-

```
 class Allocation
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int AllocationId { get; set;}

        [Display(Name = "CountryID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RightID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int RightId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add a `DbContext` ? `DbSet` ?

```
public class AllocationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Allocation> Allocation { get; set; }
}
```

EF needs to know which entities to generate.

`DbContext` figures out what classes to include in the model by looking at the `DbSet` properties that are defined.

You can add the `DbSet` line to your existing (if you already have one) `DbContext`.

Also note, you should add the `[Key]` Data Annotation above `AllocationId`:

```
[Key]
[Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
public int AllocationId { get; set;}
```

EDIT: Thanks Colin for the comment, the you don't have to add `[Key]` annotation as the `AllocationId`is in the correct Id convention which will be processed as key.

Comment: while I am adding Dbset in datacontext I am getting following error:--Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Assetry.Model.Allocation>' is less accessible than property 'Assetry.Model.VidZapperDataContext.Allocations' D:\e10\GitHub\assetry\source\Assetry.Model\Model\VidZapperDataContext.cs 146 34 Assetry.Data

Comment: Make the class public

Comment: Good answer. But you don't have to add the Key annotation. In the absence of an annotation, by convention, EF will assume that an int field named <Model>Id is the key.

Comment: Dbset is public already.I have written following code in DbContext:-- public DbSet<Allocation> Allocations { get; set; }

Comment: And the containing class ? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992928/c-inconsistent-accessibility-property-type

Comment: `public Allocation...`

Answer (score 1):

While adding any migration for new table then make sure that the model class should also be added in DbContext. For ex. For Allocation Model I have added

```
public DbSet<Allocation> Allocation { get; set; }
```

in DbContext but then I was getting "Inconsistent accessibility" error then I just removed "public" keyword from DbSet code.Now the code becomes

```
DbSet<Allocation> Allocation { get; set; }
```

Now it works properly.